# Question about critical region of a test

Tags: statistics

**Question:** Someone pretends to have telepathic gifts in the sense that if you randomly draw one card from a set with as many red as black cards, he has probability 0.6 of naming the correct color instead of probability 0.5. To test this, we procees as follows: we let him guess 25 consecutive times, where the drawn card is put back every time. If he guesses correctly at least 17 times, we believe him; otherwise we do not. State the null and alternative hypothesis and the critical region.

So according to the answer model $H_{0} : p \geq 0.6$ versus $H_{1}: p < 0.6$ and $K = \{17, \cdots, 25\}$.

To my understanding the critical region consists of the values that we reject the null hypothesis. We reject the null hypothesis if the person guesses correctly less than 17 times, so to my understanding the critical region $K$ should be $K = \{0, \cdots, 16\}$. Can somebody explain why my answer is wrong?

Comment: Hi: your null should be an equality but that's not so important. What the question probably wants you to calculate is the $\alpha$ level of the test which is the probability of rejecting the null when it's actually true. So, you need to calculate the probability of him getting 16 or less correct answers, when the true $p = 0.6$. This can be done using the binomial distribution where $p = 0.6$ and $n=25$.